What's a simple, standard way to tinker with a running app?
Given an index.js script that defines an app within a variable (i.e. a collection of in-memory state and methods), how would you go about ensuring that calls to run the script operate on an existing instance of the app, and not just create new instances?
For example, consider this app that just defines a counter, and methods to start an increment interval, pause the interval, and read the current count:
// ####################################################
// Define app
// ####################################################

const app = (() => {
    let counterInterval;
    let counter = 0;

    function startCounter() {
        counterInterval = setInterval(() => counter++, 1000);
    }

    function pauseCounter() {
        clearInterval(counterInterval);
    }

    function showCounter() {
        console.log(counter);
    }

    return {
        startCounter,
        pauseCounter,
        showCounter,
    }
})();

// ####################################################
// Run selected app method
// ####################################################

const argvs = process.argv.slice(2);
const [command, ...args] = argvs;

if (command === 'startCounter') {
    app.startCounter();
}

if (command === 'pauseCounter') {
    app.pauseCounter();
}

if (command === 'showCounter') {
    app.showCounter();
}

If I run node ./index.js startCounter, the app runs and the terminal is locked into the process. How can I make it so that:

The process runs in the background; and
Subsequent calls to node ./index.js showCounter show the value of the counter within the app that was originally ran (as opposed to creating new processes)?

The requirement seems to me like quite a common use case, so I'm thinking that there must be a mechanism in NodeJS that provides for this, but I can't find one. Do I have to use third party toolkits for this?

Why not just attach a debugger? Node supports this via --inspect.

You need a process/deamon/server that runs in the background, and a cli tool/client that query this server with some kind of IPC (e.g. network/unix socket).

A solution to my comment. As said, you need two processes that communicate with each other. A simple way to do this, is a network socket. You did not say what OS you are using. If you use windows, you need to adapt the network creating/connecting stuff.
index.js
const process = require("process");


process.env = Object.assign({
    DEAMON: "false",
    SOCKET: "/tmp/ipc-test.sock"
}, process.env);


console.log(`DAEMON: ${process.env.DEAMON}`)


if (process.env.DEAMON === "true") {
    require("./server.js");
} else {
    require("./client.js");
}

server.js
const net = require("net");
const fs = require("fs");


// cleanup previously used socket
try {
    fs.unlinkSync(process.env.SOCKET);
} catch (err) {
    if (err.code !== "ENOENT") {
        console.error(err);
    }
}

let counterInterval = null;
let counter = 0;

function startCounter() {
    counterInterval = setInterval(() => {
        counter++;
    }, 1000);
}

function pauseCounter() {
    clearInterval(counterInterval);
}


let server = net.createServer();
server.listen(process.env.SOCKET);

server.on("listening", () => {
    console.log(`listening on ${process.env.SOCKET}`)
});


server.on("connection", (client) => {

    console.log("Client connected");

    client.on("data", (data) => {

        let command = data.toString();
        console.log("Client send command:", command)

        if (command === 'startCounter') {

            startCounter();
            client.write("started");

        } else if (command === 'pauseCounter') {

            pauseCounter();
            client.write("paused");

        } else if (command === 'showCounter') {

            client.write(`${counter}`);

        } else {

            client.write(`command "${command}" is invalid`);

        }

    });

});

client.js
const net = require("net");

let [command] = process.argv.slice(2);
let socket = net.connect(process.env.SOCKET);

socket.once("data", (response) => {

    console.log(response.toString());
    socket.destroy();

});

// send command over unix socket
socket.write(command);

The concept of the program is simple: Start the server/background service with DAEMON=true node index.js and try to send commands to the server node index.js showCounter|startCounter|stopCounter|foo
When you run the server (DEAMON=true nodemon index.js) the node.js process creates a network socket, and listens for clients that may connect. If so, a client sends a command and the server executes it. (startCounter, stopCounter, etc...)
The client part is also very simple: It connects to the network socket, and forwards the command passed as command line argument. When the command is not implemented in the server it responds with "invalid comment".
Pretty simple and straight forward.
